# Поиск НОДа с помощью bash

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, инспекция-кода

Изучаю bash. Хочу вывести наименьший общий делитель на экран, но никак не получается. Не могли вы мы указать на мои ошибки ?

```
#!/bin/bash

result=1

nod_func ()
{
    local n=$1
    local m=$2

    if [[ n -eq 0 ]]
    then
        return m
    elif [[ m -eq 0 ]]
    then
        return n
    fi



    if [[ n -ge m ]]
    then
        local let "r = n % m"
        nod_func m r
    else
        local let "r = m % n"
        nod_func n r
    fi  
}

let "result = nod"

read t k

result=nod_func t k

echo "$result"
```

И есть ряд непонятностей... Например, как с помощью арифметических действий (`let`) получить локальную переменную в функции, правильно ли я делаю ? Правильно вызываю функцию и получаю результат из нее ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.opennet.ru/docs/RUS/bash_scripting_guide/c2792.html

Пример 8-1. Наибольший общий делитель

```
#!/bin/bash
# gcd.sh: поиск наибольшего общего делителя
#         по алгоритму Эвклида

#  Под "наибольшим общим делителем" (нод) двух целых чисел
#+ понимается наибольшее целое число, которое делит оба делимых без остатка.

#  Алгоритм Эвклида выполняет последовательное деление.
#  В каждом цикле,
#+ делимое  <---  делитель
#+ делитель <---  остаток
#+ до тех пор, пока остаток не станет равным нулю (остаток = 0).
#+ The gcd = dividend, on the final pass.
#
#  Замечательное описание алгоритма Эвклида можно найти
#  на сайте Jim Loy, http://www.jimloy.com/number/euclids.htm.


# ------------------------------------------------------
# Проверка входных параметров
ARGS=2
E_BADARGS=65

if [ $# -ne "$ARGS" ]
then
  echo "Порядок использования: `basename $0` первое-число второе-число"
  exit $E_BADARGS
fi
# ------------------------------------------------------


gcd ()
{

                                 #  Начальное присваивание.
  dividend=$1                    #  В сущности, не имеет значения
  divisor=$2                     #+ какой из них больше.
                                 #  Почему?

  remainder=1                    #  Если переменные неинициализировать,
                                 #+ то работа сценария будет прервана по ошибке
                                 #+ в первом же цикле.

  until [ "$remainder" -eq 0 ]
  do
    let "remainder = $dividend % $divisor"
    dividend=$divisor            # Повторить цикл с новыми исходными данными
    divisor=$remainder
  done                           # алгоритм Эвклида

}                                # последнее $dividend и есть нод.


gcd $1 $2

echo; echo "НОД чисел $1 и $2 = $dividend"; echo


# Упражнение :
# --------
#  Вставьте дополнительную проверку входных аргументов,
#+ и предусмотрите завершение работы сценария с сообщением об ошибке, если
#+ входные аргументы не являются целыми числами.

exit 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Если Вы хотите получить значение из функции. можно получить его через переменную `$?`

```
nod_func t k

result=$?

echo "$result"
```

С командой `let` работать не сложно

```
let a=a+5         # Эквивалентно "a = a + 5"
```

если локально в функции

```
func ()
{
  local n=$1
  local m=$2
  local r=0
  let r=n+m
  return $r  
}

func 3 4 
r=$?
printf  " %d\n" $r
```

Comment: Да, это понятно. А вот как посчитать с помощью `let` внутри функции, чтобы переменная была локальной. Вот это `local let "r = n % m"` правильно ?